# My Solr Server shows old data every second day

Tags: solr, stale

Am using solr with my application , specially for certain search module.
I had a failure few days back with which the entity audit table went out of sync.
After rectifying that issue whenever i add some data , it disappears the next day and solr shows the data which was there before that failure .
Say I add 500 users to my app on day 1 , go to solr admin UI and query *:* , it gives me all ( old data + new 500 ) , however when I login again next day and look for solr data , it gives that old data , does not shows newly added 500 .

After a delta-sync import , it starts to show correct one , but again back to square one the next day.

I suspect it to be some stale restoration happening , but seeking help as its haunting me now for a while.

Tried solr sync , but it works for then and there , and shows stale data the next day again .

Comment: Are you issuing actual hard commits or just softcommits? If you never hard commit the data, you can end up in a situation like this when your server gets restarted.

Comment: @MatsLindh - Hard Commit is issued  everytime.

Comment: Look at the index files in your `data` directory - check what the last changed dates are when both before and after. Run md5sum on them to see if they have changed between the two dates. Are you re-importing anything between the two times it changes? (i.e. can it be a borked import procedure?)

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh , however i just deleted that solr core completely and recreated it . Now its working fine and is stable too .